# Can't find the openssl.cnf file on my mac

Tags: macos, ssl, ssh, openssl

I am trying to locate the "openssl.cnf" file on my mac, and I haven't found it in these locations:

```
 /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
 /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
 /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

There is no "ssl" folder to begin with...

When I type the command "openssl version" on the terminal, it gives me:
OpenSSL 0.9.8za 5

so what could be the problem?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

On my <strike>Yosemite</strike> El Capitan system:

```
$ locate openssl.cnf
/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
```

On <strike>Sierra</strike> <strike>High Sierra</strike> Mojave, I have two copies of openssl.cnf with different contents:

```
$ locate openssl.cnf
/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
/private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

I think `/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf` is still the "official" reference. The second one was installed for some particular piece of software.

On Catalina, I have *three* copies:

```
% locate openssl.cnf
/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
/private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Again, I believe `/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf` is the "official" copy of the file. `/private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` is a private copy of the file for some software on the system which needs its own copy. `/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` is a "template" which the system can use to detect changes to `/private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`.

Answer (score 9):

If you installed OpenSSL via Homebrew, it is at `/usr/local/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf`

Comment: Of note: I installed `openssl` using Homebrew and my conf file _isn't_ at this location.  Using the `locate openssl.cnf` command explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27724156/378136 helped me identify where my file was.

Answer (score 5):

```
openssl version -a
```

will give folder in which openssl was compiled in a OPENSSLDIR output section

Answer (score 0):

Where the various openssl.cnf files are located becomes confusing if there are multiple versions. I generally want to know which cnf file is being used.

You can directly find the openssl directory by using

`openssl version -d`

If you've installed openssl in a virtual environment, this should show the applicable directory in the given environment where the command is run.